# wagtail cms: how to sort users by last login

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I(and my customer) want to sort users in the backend (menu > settings > users) by last login. By default I'm only able to sort by name and by username. What is the best practice to solve that? Also in version 5 I did not found this function.

Comment: It's not clear by this question where you mean, do you mean in the listing that shows in the admin Users list? Or in a custom Report? Or somewhere else in the admin interface?

This may also be good as a Django question as it's likely the same User ordering that Django uses by default. Maybe reword and re-tag this as a Django question also.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - I edited my question and added the django tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the User index view https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/wagtail/users/views/users.py#L67. Then you can do this quick and dirty:

Subclass it (somewhere):

```
from wagtail.users.views.users import Index

class UserIndex(Index):
    def get_valid_orderings(self):
        return super().get_valid_orderings() + ["last_login"]
```

And monkey-patch the relevant urlpatterns at https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/wagtail/users/urls/users.py

```
from django.urls import path
from wagtail.users.urls.users import urlpatterns
from some.path import UserIndex

urlpatterns[0] = path("", UserIndex.as_view(), name="index")
```

AFAIK, wagtail does not provide an easy way to configure or adapt its admin views like the common django admin. You can easily add new ones, though.

Comment: Now that I look at it again, the view has a method `get_valid_orderings` that returns `["name", "username"]`. Possibly, it is enough to override that one and add "last_login". If you need to add more logic like reverse order,  you can override `get_ordering` (https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/11b9448dc07ca556c9a478eeedc5a3631a9c2297/wagtail/admin/views/generic/models.py#L314)

Comment: Maybe it's a bad question but how can I override the method `get_valid_orderings`?

Comment: I edited my answer. This is however untested, and I would expect (if it works at all) the most recent logins to come last.

Comment: I tried it - it does not work and breaks the functionality of the buttons (e.g. add user, edit user, etc.)